# Why is: $\lim_{x\to 0+} x\ln x = \lim_{y\to \infty} -\frac{\ln y}{y}$ true?

Tags: limits

In class the following equivalence was used: $$\lim_{x\to 0+} x\ln x = \lim_{y\to \infty} -\frac{\ln y}{y}$$
Why is does this hold and what is the general rule here (when is switching the values to which $x$ converges allowed)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By a change of variable $x=\frac1y \to 0$ as $y\to \infty$ we have the identity

$$x\ln x = \frac1y \ln \left(\frac1y\right) = -\frac{\ln y}{y}$$

using that $-\ln a=\ln \frac1a$.

Comment: You are a lightning :-) my congratulations.